# Select Query : Two tables , Select names of all employees whose salary is GREATER than employee "ABC"

Tags: mysql, sql

Two tables

Employee

```
empid
ename
```

Salary

```
empid
salary
```

select names of all employees whose salary is GREATER than employee "ABC"

Comment: can you post your attempted query that didn't work?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select e.name
from   Employee e join Salary s using(empid) 
where  s.salary > (select salary  as ABC_salary 
                   from   Employee e join Salary s using(empid) 
                   where  e.name = 'ABC')
```

| name |
| --- |
| BAD |
| DVS |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=703b982478a2f22e33b775c049e08552)